# Visual Studio Team Services Work Item Fields - Rule limitations

Tags: azure-devops

I am utilizing VSTS to track custom work items in the VSTS interface. Two fields have been added to this custom work item that are of importance: Customer Name, Customer ID - 1:1 relationship

There are slightly more than 500 Customer Names that I need to use for the data in these Work Item fields (more than the max allowed in a pick list).

What I am trying to do is essentially perform a "lookup" function in the Customer ID field using information entered in the Customer Name field.

My questions are:
1. What are the maximum number of custom rules I can make in order to complete this lookup?
2. Is there a way in VSTS to create a custom picklist in field 2 based off the value of a field 1 like there is in TFS?

Comment: Answered the first question - it's 1024. Saving in case anyone else will need this information in the future: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=vsts

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

> 1. What are the maximum number of custom rules I can make in order to complete this lookup?

As you found the answer, the maximum rules are 1024.

> 2. Is there a way in VSTS to create a custom picklist in field 2 based off the value of a field 1 like there is in TFS?

You can add rules to set the value for Customer Name field based on the value of the Customer ID by work item **rules**.

Such as below example, the `customname` will be `Banana` if the `customId` is `2`.

[image]

**Note:** if the picklist value of the field 2 over maximum, you can define the field 2 as string.